# Which mood is created with "everyone should visit"?

Tags: grammar, british-english, auxiliary-verbs

Which mood is created with the sentence, "Everyone should visit..."  with the use of the auxiliary verb?  I have decided already that it is not the imperative mood.

Comment: Really? I think you could (and people probably have) write an entire PhD thesis on this topic.

Comment: Putting "PLEASE HELP" in the title while misspelling "English" is very off-putting. It is a shame and a slap in everybody's face that you're now getting reputation for this. Try harder next time.

Comment: I agree with Neil Coffey. This is no trivial question and deserves a close examination.

Comment: However, I think that the author should provide a context.

Comment: He did, 19 minutes ago, in a comment to my answer.

Comment: Very sorry, @RegDwight ΒВBẞ8 - I do know how to spell English, it was a mere typo as the question was written in haste.

Thank you very much for the answers, they have been very useful.

Comment: For more context needed the original sentence was, "I believe everyone should visit Snowdonia at least once in their lifetime." For my english coursework I need to write a comparative commentary essay, so i was wondering what sentence mood was created. I originally put that it created the imperative mood, however this was marked incorrect.

Comment: There have been a couple of suggestions about "imperative mood". An imperative isn't just 'any old thing giving a command': it's a specific syntactic structure. No, "should" isn't an imperative here.

Answer (score 6):

It might be more helpful to consider the question in terms of modality rather than mood (with which it nevertheless overlaps). In the words of the linguist Larry Trask, modality is ‘associated with the expression of obligation, prohibition, necessity, possibility and ability’. Modality is expressed in English through the modal verbs, of which *should* is one, and whose main use is to express weak obligation. That is the role it performs in your example. (The expression of obligation is known to linguists as *deontic modality*.)

Comment: @ Barrie England. What you write is certainly correct and better expressed than what I wrote, but is there such a great difference in meaning between "weak obligation" and "piece of advice, or suggestion"? I don't grasp why I keep being downvoted.

Comment: @Barrie England - _Should_ appears also to express a sense of duty, a condition or an expectation. I think!

Comment: @Paola: You may have been downvoted because, whatever ‘Everyone should visit’ is, it isn’t conditional. This is not the place, I’m afraid, to give a lesson on English modal verbs, but a more precise meaning of what was intended in the OP’s example would depend on its context. ‘Weak obligation’ is what it suggests in isolation.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Weak obligation is what it appears to suggest in the OP's example.

Comment: Paola, you were downvoted because you wrote about grammatical forms, which is not what the OP was asking for. That was not an easy one, I'll give you that.

Comment: @Giorgiomastrò.  Again, I do not understand. Would it be different if I just said "conditional" or used the term "mood"? Would I stick to the question better? Pupil asked about a sentence in which he used an auxiliary and wanted to know what mood it was.

Comment: I do think this answer glosses over a number of problems, including the key issue of how we avoid the definition of "modality" as being circular (is the *only* reason for lumping 'obligation' etc together and call them 'modality' is because they're the things expressed by modal verbs, and if not, what is the concrete, reliable trait that these notions have in common and mark them out as 'special'?)

Comment: @NeilCoffey: Well, of course it does. None of us is going to write a book here!

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at what the main dictionaries say about *should*:

- **Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary**: used to say or ask what is the correct or best thing to do
- **Merriam-Webster**: used in auxiliary function to express obligation,
  propriety, or expediency

If I grasp what you mean by "mood", then the mood created by "should" is that of a suggestion: e.g. "Everyone should visit Venice. It's wonderful!"

I wouldn't say that it's imperative, since "should" is used to express something that one finds useful or desirable, not a moral obligation or an indefeasable duty.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, it is imperative.

Comment: Considering that the OP stated that he/she does not believe it is the imperative mood, can you expand on why you think it is the imperative mood?

Comment: ohh...sorry for captilzing. To me, 'should' symbolizes imperation.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a consensus on this matter: it really depends on your particular stance and analysis that you choose to adopt.

Usually "mood" is a label for "the grammaticalisation of modality", where 'modality' means something like 'representation of an event in a non-factual way'-- i.e. your representation is 'coloured' with various notions, typically indicating some 'scale' of notions such as necessity, possibility, volition etc.

One immediate problem is that there's no clear-cut list of concepts that definitely must or must not complete this list, and it's not clear what semantically these notions really have in common other than "the types of things usually conveyed by modal verbs"-- i.e. our definitions are a little bit circular.

But accepting that, which category of modality is represented by a particular modal verb (or other construction) is really a matter of which particular framework you want to invent or subscribe to. However, a common broad categorisation would be to talk about:

- "epistemic necessity" when 'should' (and 'must', 'have to', 'is bound to' etc) are used to indicate the speaker's judgement/opinion of likelihood;
- "root necessity" when they are used to indicate the speaker's more objective assessment of whether, if you lile, 'the universe forces the event to be true'.

In this case, the speaker is essentially indicating their opinion, so you would probably refer to it as epistemic necessity.

There is another, broader, view of "mood" which simply looks at whether events are portrayed in a way that can be agreed with or denied. So for example, note that it is easy to use a 'tag'-based utterance to agree with the following statements:

> It's raining. : Yes, it is.
>
> It should rain later. : Yes, it should.

whereas that's not possible in these cases, as there's no real fact to "agree" with and we can't use the same procedure for forming a corresponding tag:

> Let it rain!
>
> Rain and see if I care!

(Of course, we could say "Yes, let it!" or "No, don't let it!" but these are different syntactic structures to the 'simple' tag, and we're not agreeing with the *factual* content of the utterance.)

So from this viewpoint, 'should' here doesn't indicate any special mood at all. Whereas in "let it..." and the simple imperative "rain!", we would be led to conclude that these are examples of a different mood.

So I repeat: there isn't a single answer to this question. It depends on what framework you choose to adopt and is quite a complex matter.

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to decide if this categorisation, and indeed the notion of "mood" at all as it is typically applied to English, really buys you terribly much.